# ZedGraph - Timer or Thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, zedgraph

Currently, I am using a thread to autofill a `zedgraph chart`. The problem is that it is very slow and that is not good for the production. 
Knowing that:
1. There is a `Thread` running background to get fresh data from remote server and store them in a local text file.
 
2. There is another Thread accesses and reads data from the local file and refresh the zedgraph chart.
*Personnaly I think this makes the application running very slowly.*
`Timer` component may be better to handle this kind of stuff.
Does anyone has experience in ZedGraph Live Data?
Or any advice would be welcomed.
**EDIT: UPDATE UI**
Also I would like to know how to update the UI within a Thread so that the user does not have to close and open the form to view the chart.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know how much data you put into that file but 99.9% of the time it's better to keep the data in memory so you can access it quicker. (in other words save it in a variable and read it from the graph's thread)

Comment: Why would a Timer be better? I do not get the point.

Comment: have you thought about a backgorundworker without file access?

Comment: Like @dragon112 says, do you really need the local file for something else?  If not, use inter-thread comms, (producer-consumer queue, perhaps), to transfer the data directly - that's a big advantage of threads - all share the same app memory.

Comment: hi @dragon112, do you have any link explaining the use of this? getting data with a thread, save in memory and access them to update the UI.

Comment: @MartinJames what about inter-thread comms ? knowing that I have 12 small Forms inside a splitContainer and all the Forms have to be loaded at startup. What can I adopt in this case ?

Comment: Hello, no-one can suggest an issue?

Answer (score 1):

The way I would go about this is as follows:

You make a class that holds the data (this can also be the same class you already have) for the example I will call it `InformationHolder`.

```
class InformationHolder {
    private static InformationHolder singleton = null;
    public List<float> graphData; //Can be any kind of variable (List<GraphInfo>, GraphInfo[]), whatever you like best.

    public static InformationHolder Instance() {
        if (singleton == null) {
            singleton = new InformationHolder();
        }

        return singleton;
    }
}
```

Now you need a class that will get your information in the background, parses it and inserts it into the above class.

Example with `Thread.Sleep()`:

```
class InformationGartherer {
    private Thread garthererThread;

    public InformationGartherer() {
        garthererThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GartherData));
    }

    private void GartherData() {
        while (true) {
            List<float> gartheredInfo = new List<float>();

            //Do your garthering and parsing here (and put it in the gartheredInfo variable)

            InformationHolder.Instance().graphData = gartheredInfo;

            graphForm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker( //you need to have a reference to the form
                   delegate {
                       graphForm.Invalidate(); //or another method that redraws the graph
                   }));

            Thread.Sleep(100); //Time in ms
        }
    }
}
```

Example with `Timer`:

```
class InformationGartherer {
    private Thread garthererThread;
    private Timer gartherTimer;

    public InformationGartherer() {
        //calling the GartherData method manually to get the first info asap.
        garthererThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GartherData));

        gartherTimer = new Timer(100); // time in ms
        gartherTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerCallback);
        gartherTimer.Start();
    }

    private void TimerCallback(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
        gartherThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GartherData));
    }

    private void GartherData() {
        List<float> gartheredInfo = new List<float>();

        //Do your garthering and parsing here (and put it in the gartheredInfo variable)

        InformationHolder.Instance().graphData = gartheredInfo;

        graphForm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker( //you need to have a reference to the form
                delegate {
                    graphForm.Invalidate(); //or another method that redraws the graph
                }));
    }
}
```

To get the reference to the form you could do the same trick as I used with the InformationHolder: using a singleton.
When you want to use the information just get it from the `InformationHolder` like so:

```
InformationHolder.Instance().graphData;
```

As I said this is how I personally would solve this. There might be a better solution I'm not aware of. If you have any questions you can post them below.

Comment: Thanks @dragon112 for your reply. I have question,,the class InformationGartherer has to be instanciated somewhere in the code and where? in the Form or where ? Can I call this class InformationHolder directly in the Form?

Comment: Really, I don't know how to use these functions. Can you modify in a way to get fresh data from a remote server? Something like inside the Thread: - Connect to remote server; - Get Time and OCHL data, store them to a List variable; - Send these variables to zedGraph to draw chart.

Comment: Basically you should use something like `HttpWebRequest` to `POST` to a web service and possebly receive a response. If you need to use a `GET` request you can use `WebRequest`. There are tons of examples out there. If you can't figure it out I'll try to help you out.

Comment: If you call the `InformationHolder` it will initiate itself (in the `Shared()` method). The `InformationGartherer` however doesn't have such a method and needs to be created by a normal `new InformationGartherer()` call.